# Python Azure Functions, EventGrid Trigger

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I am pretty new to azure, and struggling with the python function triggers from eventGrid.
I am using ready templates created from azure for python and getting errors.
I will share the files.

(**init**.py)

```
import json
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(event: func.EventGridEvent):

    result = json.dumps(
        {
            "id": event.id,
            "data": event.get_json(),
            "topic": event.topic,
            "subject": event.subject,
            "event_type": event.event_type,
        }
    )

    logging.info("Python EventGrid trigger processed an event: %s", result)
```

function.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventGridTrigger",
      "name": "event",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py"
}
```

host.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  }
}
```

and the that's the dataset that i sent to event grid

```
{
  "topic": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionID}/resourcegroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/event",
  "subject": "eventhubs/test",
  "eventType": "captureFileCreated",
  "eventTime": "2017-07-14T23:10:27.7689666Z",
  "id": "{id}",
  "data": {
    "fileUrl": "https://test.blob.core.windows.net/debugging/testblob.txt",
    "fileType": "AzureBlockBlob",
    "partitionId": "1",
    "sizeInBytes": 0,
    "eventCount": 0,
    "firstSequenceNumber": -1,
    "lastSequenceNumber": -1,
    "firstEnqueueTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "lastEnqueueTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
  },
  "dataVersion": "", 
  "metadataVersion": "1" 
}
```

and the error that i am getting is

```
fail: Function.{functionName}[3]
Executed 'Functions.{functionName}' (Failed, Id={someID}, Duration=121ms)
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: Functions.{functionName}
System.InvalidOperationException: Exception binding parameter 'event'
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
```

probably it is super easy mistake somewhere above but i couldn't find it..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> python fail: Function.{functionName}[3] Executed 'Functions.{functionName}' (Failed, Id={someID}, Duration=121ms) Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: Functions.{functionName}  System.InvalidOperationException: Exception binding parameter 'event' System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.

The above error is quite a common generic error message. It appears when your application hits some limitations of the Event grid.

If It is reaching the maximum hits of limitations of Event Grid refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry)

> Note: Event Grid triggers aren't natively supported in an internal load balancer App Service Environment. The trigger uses an HTTP request that can't reach the function app without a gateway into the virtual network.

If you are using a ***consumption*** plan try to use the ***dedicated*** plan to avoid this issue.

Refer here to [reliable event processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reliable-event-processing) to relate this error.

Check the limitations of Event Grid and choose the appropriate plan to for your requirement.

#### Reference:

azure function fails with function invocation [exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/598791/azure-function-fails-with-functioninvocationexcept.html)